# Out of Office Automated reply Subject Line in Spanish

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2003

I have a bit of an odd issue with outlook 2003 SP3. a few of our users are currently using their out of office replies, however the subject line is en Español "Respuesta automática de Fuera de la oficina:"

I've checked the regional settings on both client and server (his email is handled by exchange 2003) and they're both set to UK English.

Any ideas? I'm getting a little stumped...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESOLVED

When the account was initially set up, for some unknown reason it was set to the Spanish Language and Region and as such the out of office subject line was set to Spanish.

Running outlook.exe /resetfoldernames resets the mailbox language to the current language of the computer you are running it from and has fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook has some of it's own language settings that are separate from the Regional Settings of the OS, so you may want to check those out if you haven't already.

Here's some XP/Outlook 2003 instructions that will hopefully get you there:

1. In Microsoft Windows XP, on the Windows Start menu, point to All Programs, point to Microsoft Office, point to Microsoft Office Tools, and then click Microsoft Office 2003 Language Settings.
2. Click the Enabled Languages tab.
3. In the Choose the language that defines default behavior in Microsoft Office applications box, select the language you want, and then click OK.
4. A message appears describing the effects of the change. To continue, click Continue and lose customizations.

[Source](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/outlook-help/change-the-default-language-setting-HP003088462.aspx)

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I looked into this as well, we only have English UK and English US enabled.